# OneNote freezes?

Tags: office365, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I've got a user whose OneNote freezes everytime they use the interactivity of a SMART MX075-V3 smartboard. They have nothing running in the background. The version of OneNote that they use is Microsoft 365 2310 Build 16.0.169124.20054 16 bit on a Windows 10 Enterprise Version OS Build 19045.3570. After freezing the calibration of the board to OneNote seems to be out. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: I have One Note on numerous machines (All Windows 11 Pro 23H2) and no issues.  Try this:   Uninstall Office, restart and reinstall Office.  Be aware One Note is shifting to the Microsoft Cloud Version. I use this now.  The One Note databases are different between the two versions.

Comment: You may also go to Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Applications, check if there is any related record.